# C Language - Are static initialized strings in any way const by default?

Tags: c, string, declaration

A declaration like this:

```
char* string = "Test";
```

Does carries some implicity const?

I wanna know whether the next examples makes sense or not.

```
const char* string = "Test";
char* const string = "Test";
const char* const string = "Test";
```

Comment: C99 - _6.4.5: For character string literals, the array elements **have
type char**, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence;_ but on the other hand: _If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined._

Answer (score 2):

```
char* string = "Test";
```

Don't do that. This should yield a warning because that's really a static string, but it doesn't. If you write to the string it will explode.

```
const char* string = "Test";
```

Correct.

```
char* const string = "Test";
```

Not correct. This means that the `string` pointer cannot change but its contents can, which is not very useful besides being wrong.

```
const char* const string = "Test";
```

Correct. Now neither `string` pointer nor its contents can change. I rarely bother with const on the right side of a `*` but it has its uses.

If you really want a writeable string use

```
char string[] = "Test";
```

Comment: What's wrong with `char* string = "Test";`??? It's a perfectly legal declaration of a constant string. It causes no warning even when compiled with the strictest flags.

Comment: The storage duration of a string (or other object) has no bearing on whether `const` should be associated with it

Comment: `char* const string = "Test";` is correct according to the C Standard

Comment: The question was about implicity const. I know that it is legal.